# convert date into index on dataframe for default date

Tags: python, pandas, string-to-datetime

Is it possible to convert a series of dates in a column into a numeric index using pd.to_datetime? After that put it into a variable so I can print the value in a single variable.

```
default_date = ''
print(f'value of default_date' : {default_date}')
```

This is the data output
[image]

For example:
2021-07-01 to 0
2021-07-02 to 1

Comment: Could you please provide an example input and output?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetiem(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')
```

Or:

```
df = df.set_index('date')
df.index = pd.to_datetiem(df.index)
```